# How can I make Least Square method work at this engineering code?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

So I have this issue, x are the variables it should minimize to achieve determined objective function F down to zero.
It happens this doesn't change or gives me absurd values during the iteration, I think I'm messing with variable type, vector wrongly inputed... I don't know...

The objective here is: I need to vary c1 and w2 (velocities) until the flow in every stage (G_perfil_M and G_perfil_F) is coincident or with the minimum difference as possible between each other, this max error defined by the max error at levenberg marquadt function at the end of the file.

Please, I appreciate any help!

```
from math import pi, cos
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
from iapws import IAPWS97
# These functions bellow are unit conversions from water table IAPWS
# to enter code here`to known-by-me units that I input inside the program,
# such as pressure, temperature, etc..
def h_pt(p,t):
    h = IAPWS97(P=p*0.1,T=t+273.15)
    return h.h

def t_ph(p,h):
    t = IAPWS97(P=p*0.1,h=h)
    T = t.T-273.15
    return T 

def s_ph(p,h):
    s = IAPWS97(P=p*0.1,h=h)
    return s.s

def p_hs(h,s):
    p = IAPWS97(h=h,s=s)
    P = p.P*10
    return P

def v_ph(p,h):
    v = IAPWS97(P=p*0.1,h=h)
    return v.v

def visc_din_ph(p,h):
    visc_din = IAPWS97(P=p*0.1,h=h)
    return visc_din.Vapor.mu

def x_ph(p,h):
    x = IAPWS97(P=p*0.1,h=h)
    return x.x

def sound_ph(p,h):
    sound = IAPWS97(P=p*0.1,h=h)
    return sound.w0
   
def k_ph(p,h):
    k = IAPWS97(P=p*0.1,h=h)
    return k.gamma0

def h_ps(p,s):
    h = IAPWS97(P=p*0.1,s=s)
    return h.h

def v_ps(p,s):
    v = IAPWS97(P=p*0.1,s=s)
    return v.v

def t_ps(p,s):
    t = IAPWS97(P=p*0.1,s=s)
    T = t.T-273.15
    return T
# Setting up the variables
nmax_est = 50
nrpm = np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # speed in rpm
c1= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # steam velocity at nozzle abs
w2= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # steam velocity at rotor abs
c1t= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # steam velocity at nozzle theoric
w2t = np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # steam velocity at rotor theoric
p0 = np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # pressure at inlet
T0= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # Temperature at inlet
i0= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # Enthalpy at inlet
v0= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # specific volume
s0= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # entropy
c0 = np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # velocity at nozzle inlet
p1= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # pressure at nozzle outlet
i1= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # Enthalpy at nozzle outlet
v1= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # specific volume
s1= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # entropy
c1u = np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float)
u1 = np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # tangential speed
u2 = np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # tangential speed
p2= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # pressure at rotor outlet
i2= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # Enthalpy at rotor outlet
v2= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # specific volume
s2= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # entropy
p2_fixo = np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # given exhaust pressure
alfa1= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # outlet nozzle angle
A1 = np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # Area nozzle
A2 = np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # Area rotor
rotalpy = np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # Energy
G_perfil_M= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # Rotor flow
G_perfil_F= np.zeros((nmax_est), dtype=np.float) # Nozzle flow

# Bellow we have the inputs
stage = 3
coef_vel = [0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91]
p0[0]=23.91
T0[0]=280.0
p2_fixo = 2.5
nrpm = [5372.0, 5372.0, 5372.0, 5372.0]
d1 = [553.0, 553.0, 557.0, 562.0]
d2 = [553.5, 553.5, 557.5, 562.5]
A1 = [0.001949, 0.005134, 0.007255, 0.001136]
A2 = [0.009231, 0.009008, 0.011889, 0.018301]
alfa1 = [16, 12, 14, 16]

def objective_function(x):
    # Here I create the variables the least square will vary and assign this to my real variables. The idea is to vary the velocity c1 and w2
    for x_func in range(0, stage + 1, 1):
            c1[x_func] = x[2 * x_func]
            w2[x_func] = x[2 * x_func + 1]
            if x_func == stage:
                G_estagio = x[2 * x_func + 2]
    # loop thru each stage calculating pressure, entalpy and flw for each stage 
    for i in range(0, stage + 1, 1):
        if i == 0:
            i0[i] = h_pt(p0[i] , T0[i])
            s0[i] = s_ph(p0[i] , i0[i])
        else:
            p0[i] = p2[i-1]
            i0[i] = i2[i-1]
            s0[i] = s2[i-1]
        u1[i] = pi * d1[i] * nrpm[i] / 60000
        u2[i] = pi * d2[i] * nrpm[i] / 60000
        i1[i] = i0[i] - c1[i]**2 / 2000
        c1u[i] = c1[i] * cos(alfa1[i] * pi / 180)
        rotalpy[i] = i1[i] + c1[i]**2 / 2000 - u1[i] * c1u[i] / 1000
        i2[i] = rotalpy[i] + u2[i]**2 / 2000 - w2[i]** 2/ 2000
        p1[i] = p_hs(i0[i] - c1[i]**2 / (2000 * coef_vel[i]**2), s0[i])
        s1[i] = s_ph(p1[i], i1[i])
        p2[i] = p_hs(rotalpy[i] + u2[i]** 2 / 2000 - w2[i]**2 / (2000 * coef_vel[i]**2), s1[i])
        s2[i] = s_ph(p2[i], i2[i])
        v1[i] = v_ph(p1[i], i1[i])
        v2[i] = v_ph(p2[i], i2[i])
        G_perfil_F[i] = A1[i] * c1[i] / v1[i]
        G_perfil_M[i] = A2[i] * w2[i] / v2[i]  
    # Create a function to minimize at the Levenberg marquadt routine bellow
    F = np.empty((stage * 2 + 3))    
    for obj_func in range(0, stage + 1, 1):
        F[2 * obj_func] = G_perfil_F[obj_func] - G_estagio
        F[2 * obj_func + 1] = G_perfil_M[obj_func] - G_estagio
        if obj_func == stage:
            F[2 * obj_func + 2] = p2_fixo - p2[stage]
    return F
# Just create some initial values for the levenberg routine to start
initial_guess = np.zeros((stage * 2 + 3))
for guess in range(0, stage * 2 + 2,  1):
    initial_guess[guess] = 600
initial_guess[stage * 2 + 2] = 7
solution = least_squares(objective_function, initial_guess, method='lm', ftol=1e-3)
print(solution)
```

Comment: That's _a lot_ of code and it isn't clear what least squares problem is being solved, and if it might be ill-conditioned. Suggest taking the time to vectorize the code so it is clearer and  then editing the question. Also printing out the residuals of the fit and checking if it is ill conditioned is recommended.

Comment: You need to describe the problem you're trying to solve and clean up that code (why are some variables commented out? where are your code comments explaining what you intend your code to do?).

Comment: Please, mind to read the text again. I explained a little better. Thanks.